# Array of records (TStringlist based) causing Access Violation

Tags: delphi

This is my first attempt at using records. I have ~180 delimited text files each with ~250,000 lines. In each file there are up to 150 unique records with the content of the file being allocated to the matching id of the record.

```
 type
    StringsRec = Record
      id : string[2];
      Content : TStringList;
   end;
….
var
  RecArray : array of StringsRec;
  RecLen : Integer;
  iList, sl : TstringList;
….
```

Stringlists `iList` and `sl` are created and destroyed on the form create and destroy. After each file iList is cleared and the length of `RecArray` is set to 0. However I do not get that far.
The first record has 3 lines added to it’s content (`Tstringlist`). The second has 8 and the third 12. No problem so far, but when the fourth new record is created I get an access violation.

My code for checking if a new record is needed. Arec is the first 2 letters of a column in a line from the source file; it is checked for validity and both characters are alpha.

```
procedure TForm1.MakeRec(Arec : string);
var
  x : Integer;
  isThere : Boolean;
begin
  isThere := False;
  if RecLen = 0 then isThere := False
  else
    begin
      for x := 0 to iList.Count-1 do
        begin
          if copy(iList[x],1,2) = Arec then
            begin
              isThere := True;
              Exit;
            end;
        end;
    end;
  if isThere = False then
    begin
      SetLength(RecArray,Length(RecArray)+1);
      RecLen := Length(RecArray);
      RecArray[RecLen].id := Arec;
      RecArray[RecLen].Content := TStringList.Create;
      iList.Add(Arec+'='+IntToStr(RecLen));
       ShowMessage(RecArray[reclen].id + ' ' +inttostr(iList.IndexOfName(arec)));
    end;
end;
```

With the 4th record the message shown is blank but the dialog box is expanded as if some text was there
[image]
and when I try to add content I get the violation. (s2 is the Arec above)

```
RecArray[iList.IndexOfName(s2)].Content.Add(sl[x]);
```

Unless my code is full of errors I suspect that this problem is due to memory, again something I have never had to delve into before.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am using delphi 7 with Windows 11 64bit

**Edit**

I have tried stepping through the part of my code where I think the error is occurring.

[image]

On all four record creations stepping through lines, 2, 3 and 4 holding the cursor over the id shows the correct 2 letters but with the fourth record stepping to line 5 and the id becomes a string of #0000s and various other characters.

I hope this helps to narrow it down

Comment: Without further info, the most likely culprit is that iList.IndexOfName(s2) returns -1 (as in "not found"). Try splitting that line into two - first one where you assign the iList.IndexOfName(s2) to an integer variable, and the second one where you use that variable to index RecArray. You can then use the debugger to determine what value the index has before using it.

Comment: Another possibility is (if you you the value part of the iList) that the assigned value appears to be a 1-based index, and if you use that value directly as an index into the RecArray, then you'll get the wrong record. Actually, you already have that error in your `RecArray[RecLen].id := Arec;` statement, which will always access a record one position above the last one (as indices into dynamic arrays are _[0..LENGTH(RecArray)-1]_ or _[LOW(RecArray)..HIGH(RecArray)]_).

Comment: @HeartWare, Thank you for both your comments, I will look into these. But if there is an error why do the first three records ids are set and content added without a problem?

Comment: Do you have range checking turned on in your project options?  If not, then it's not checking that the element you ask for is actually there, and I think you're simply fortunate that you're trying to access somewhere that is not a problem.

Comment: @Philip J. Rayment. Thank you I just turned it on and immediately got a Range check error. If the element is not actually there then how do I ensure that the element is created. As I said this my first attempt with records

Comment: Your problem at the core is that you are accessing the RecArray with indices 1 and up, whereas you should access it with indices 0 and up. I can't see the rest of your code, but a simple change would be to (1) Assign `RecLen:=-1` if your form's `OnCreate` handler, (2) your check `RecLen=0` should thus be changed to `RecLen<0` and (3) your `RecLen := Length(RecArray);` should be changed to `RecLen := High(RecArray);`. If you use RecLen elsewhere in your code, you'll need to update those areas as well. And perhaps rename _RecLen_ to _RecHigh_ as it no longer reflects the length of the array.

Comment: @HeartWare. I missed this comment when I posted my final edit. I have since followed your suggestions and it is perfect. Thank you

Comment: IIRC StackOverflow is not meant to deal with fixing someone's code, but ask for a specific problem which could be later found back and used as reference. Your code is full of problems, especially about memory management (using TStringList is a wrong idea in a record: use an array of string instead), or using a main iList as index instead of the dynamic array itself, and a lot of similar stuff. I voted to close.

Comment: I believe that the -1 at your IndexOfName lines shouldn't be there, as the IndexOfName already returns a 0-based index.

Comment: I've rolled back your edit. It is not acceptable here to add the solution into your question. If you found a way to solve the issue and want to share it, do so by writing an answer in the space below that is provided for that purpose. See [Can I answer my own question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) for more information.

Comment: i would recommend a TobjectList with Owns Objects set to true and then inserting, adding a TStringsHolder with the same function as yout record ... The Tstringlist in the record gives me headache.. If its a learning execise i reccomend inspecting your values or the instector window (strg+ f7) the look into the values in each debugging step.

Answer (score 1):

You're fortunate that it's not getting a violation earlier.  The problem seems to me to be here:

```
SetLength(RecArray,Length(RecArray)+1);  //if the length was 3, it's now 4.
RecLen := Length(RecArray);   //So you're setting RecLen to 4.
RecArray[RecLen].id := Arec;  //You then look at element 4.
```

But the array is [0..3]!  There is no element 4.